# get absolute path of a java ee project inside a servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, path

For example,
the java ee project is in **C:\ABC.**

The servlet is in **C:\ABC\src\demo\HelloServlet.java.**

```
public void doGet(..,..){
   //how can I get the absolute path of the project(C:\ABC\)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this : request.getServletContext().getRealPath (".");